# React native launches fine on debug, but not release, crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I made a small app that runs on React-native 0.64, and uses a set of  librairies. It launches fine on Debug, when running on iPad, but not on Release. I get the following error: First throw

```
call stack:
(0x1b0b7b9d8 0x1c4efeb54 0x1b0be5d98 0x1b0be35c4 0x1b0a63ef0 0x1b2d296d8 0x104c0dc74 0x104c0e19c 0x104c0e8c8 0x10540bce4 0x10540d528 0x10541b994 0x1b0afb5e0 0x1b0af5a88 0x1b0af4ba0 0x1c785a598 0x1b33e62f4 0x1b33eb874 0x104b8dadc 0x1b07d3568)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

the package.json file is :

```
{
  "name": "maya",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.14",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.2",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.0-next.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.0-next.9",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-persist-transform-encrypt": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.10",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-persist": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/redux-persist-transform-encrypt": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.65.2",
    "react-native-keychain": "^6.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

and the file main file is App.js, it runs from index.js, and basically it updates whenever the user has successfully been connected watching account reducer on redux.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React                   from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Provider }            from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate }         from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react';
import { LogBox }              from 'react-native';

import OfflineNavigation       from './components/navigation';
import { store }               from './components/redux';
import { persistor }           from './components/redux';

LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(true);

const Application = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <OfflineNavigation />
      </Provider>
      </PersistGate>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Application;
```

Comment: I found a a bad solution, but still one, by creating another project and copying modules and code. Worked perfectly.